# Forecasting a time series in R with 3 independent variables

Tags: r, forecasting

I have  a time series of revenue and need to forecast revenue for 3 years. 
My dependent variable is Revenue and independent variables are GDP, Company wealth, and S and P 500 Index.

How should I go about it?

Can a simple Linear regression model work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To write a good R question on SO you generally provide a reproducible example of your data/code problem, showing what you've done thusfar and where you've hit a snag. Then we try to help you fix the bug in your code. What you're asking may be a better question for CrossValidated than SO, assuming that you do know the commands and you're asking more for statistical advice.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the "forecast" package in R. If your timeseries is `x` and your independent variables are in a matrix `mat`, you can utilize the `auto.arima()` function to automatically fit an arima model with covariates.

```
library(forecast)
mod <- auto.arima(x, xreg = mat)
# Forecast 12 periods
forecast(mod, h = 12)
```